# Insert blank line before line matching pattern in sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, command

I am attempting to insert blank line above a line when we match a pattern. We have a grep statement that will find the line and store the line number in a variable.

In this example I want to insert a blank line above line 1 which is the `happy` line and then insert a line above line 3 which has the text `sad`.

This works fine with a sed command however I want to use `variable` substitution for the line number in the `sed` statement and that is where it fails. Let me move on and show the example that
I have created to show what issue I am having.

Here is our sed command that works when using it without the variable:

```
sed '1i\\' test # insert blank line at top of file:
```

Here is our file named: `test` which has 3 lines:

```
Line1=happy
Line2=mad
Line3=sad
```

We have two variables for our `sed` statement:

```
1: this has the line of happy - which is 1.
2. this has the line of sad - which is 3.
```

Here is the variables that we want the `sed` statment to use:

```
h=$(grep -n happy test | cut -d : -f 1)
s=$(grep -n sad test | cut -d : -f 1)
```

Show that the `h` and `s` variables seem to work:

```
user@host:~$ echo $h
1
user@host:~$ echo $s
3
```

Show that our `sed` statement works properly to output a blank line at the beginning of the file - which is line 1 & then also for line 3.

```
sed '1i\\' test  # we test that it outputs a blank line on the top of the file first - without our variable:

user@host:~$ sed '1i\\' test 
           # here is our blank line.
happy
mad
sad

user@host:~$ sed '3i\\' test
happy
mad
           # here is our blank line for line 3.
sad
```

Now we move onto testing it with our variables defined in the command substitution variables `h` and `s` so we can try to do the same thing as we did above. 
This is where it does not work - I will not test with both variables since it does not work with the first variable. I have tried different syntax that I have researched heavily but cannot get `sed` to work with the variable.

```
sed "$si\\" test # try to insert the blank line with the variable at top of file


user@host:~$ sed '$hi\\' test # we test that it outputs a blank line on the top of the file first - with our variable with  ticks ' ':
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command  

user@host:~$ sed "$hi\\" test # we test that it outputs a blank line on the top of the file first - with our variable with  quotes " " :
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unterminated address regex


user@host:~$ sed "'$hi\\'" test # we test that it outputs a blank line on the top of the file first - with our variable with  quotes/ticks "' '" :
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I have tried several other forms of quotes/ticks ect to try to get it to work. I read around on stack-overflow significanly and found that I should use quotes around my command if using variables.

I have been given a comment to utilize the { } around my variable however when doing this it does not output a line above like it does with the real text:

```
user@host:~$ sed "${h}i\\" test # the command does not error now but does not output the line either - variable h.
happy
mad
sad

user@host:~$ sed "${s}i\\" test # the command does not error now but does not output the line either - variable s.
happy
mad
sad

user@host:~$ sed '1i\\' test
        # blank line here
happy
mad
sad
```

Comment: `${g}i`, `${h}i`; the shell is looking for the non-existing variables `$gi` and `$hi`. Alternatively, `$g i`, `$h i`.

Comment: It works with the "${gi,\\" test - as in the command does not error out but it does not output a line above the first line.

Comment: Oh, you actually need to escape the backslashes because of using double quotes: `"${g}i\\\\"`.

Comment: You shouldn't update your question with the accepted answer. The answer is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work perfectly. I tested it on Ubuntu with no issues.

```
number=3
sed $number'i\\' test.txt
```

Regards!

Comment: This works because the double backslash is within single quotes.

Comment: Yep. Exactly. :)

Comment: user@host:~$ sed $h'i\\' test
               # blank line 
happy
mad
sad

Comment: How might you reverse this and add a blank line on the next line after the pattern?

Comment: @AlexTomko ``a\\``

Answer (score 4):

Getting the line number with `grep` so you can pass it to `sed` is an antipattern.  You want to do all the processing in `sed`.

```
sed -e '/happy/i\\' -e '/sad/i\\' file
```

If indeed the action is the same in both cases, you can conflate it to a single regular expression.

```
sed '/\(happy\|sad\)/i\\' file
```

(The precise syntax will vary between `sed` dialects but you get the idea.  If your `sed` has `-r` or `-E` you can avoid the backslashes.)

Comment: I will add another edit to my question to show the bigger picture. I am using it that way to script out adding a blank line that I can use to input text through a script.

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that `"$gi"` is looking for the variable `$gi`, which doesn't exist. To avoid that, you have to either put curly braces around the variable name, as in `"${g}i"`, or put a space between the variable name and the sed command, as in `"$g i"`.

Then, because your tests that work use single quotes, the double backslash is interpreted literally. In double quotes, backslashes have to be escaped, resulting in

```
sed "${h}i\\\\" test
```

And finally, it seems this is overly complicated. To insert a blank line before a line containing a pattern, you can use this (for the example `happy`):

```
sed '/happy/s/^/\n/' test
```

This "replaces" the beginning of the line with a newline if the line matches `happy`.

Notice that inserting a newline like this doesn't work with every sed; for macOS sed, you could probably use something like

```
sed $'/happy/s/^/\\\n/' test
```

Comment: It is overly complicated because the real world file will have 1000's of lines and I need to match specific things with variable and use the variable to do other things.

Comment: Sounds like you should be writing an Awk script instead then.